# unexpacted behaviour in event javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

this is my html

```
<input type="text" id="test">
<button id="btn" > validate </button>
<span id="result"> </span>
```

and this is my javascript

```
var test = document.getElementById("test");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var result = document.getElementById("result");

var regex = /^\w+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/gi  //a very simple regex

btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
     if(regex.test(test.value)){
       result.innerHTML = "the value entered is correct ";
     }else{
       result.innerHTML = "the value entered is incorrect ";
     }
});
```

the problem here is that when i put email and click on validate button it works as expected but when you click second time on validate button it execute the else part which says the value entered is incorrect although there is still email present

Comment: As a sidenote, I hope you're not using that regex to test for emails because it's *very* wrong.

Comment: yeah i know but it behave unexpectedly

Comment: The new title obscures the problem. Nothing related with events. It's just the fact that you use a regular expression that is stateful, so using it multiple times gives different results.

Comment: and why is that can you elaborate

Comment: See the linked duplicate.

Comment: that solved my problem thank you